# Android Bluetooth Issue - Cannot resolve symbol 'addAction' & Cannot resolve symbol 'registerReceiver'

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to why the I'm getting a

> Unknown Class: BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND, Unknown Class: BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED, & Unknown Class: BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED error AND Unknown Class: mReceiver & Unknown Class: bluetoothIntentFilter that is causing me to get my Cannot resolve symbol 'addAction' & Cannot resolve symbol 'registerReceiver'

Errors that I can't resolve.  What would be causing this issue?

Here is my current code:

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.app.Activity;

public class BluetoothConnectionRepair extends Activity {
    //Assuming that the device address is registered and is connected
    private String partnerDevAdd = "11:22:33:AA:CC:FF";
    private boolean isConnected = true;

    Context context;
    IntentFilter bluetoothIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    bluetoothIntentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    Context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, bluetoothIntentFilter);
    bluetoothIntentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    Context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, bluetoothIntentFilter);
    bluetoothIntentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    Context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, bluetoothIntentFilter);

    //BroadcastReceiver for Bluetooth related checks
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (isConnected == false) {
                //Bluetooth Device discovered
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    //Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    //Check if the discovered device is one we had communication with
                    if (device.getAddress().equals(partnerDevAdd) == true) {
                        connectToExisting(device);
                    }
                }

                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                    //Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    //Check if the connected device is one we had communication with
                    if (device.getAddress().equals(partnerDevAdd) == true) {
                        isConnected = true;
                    } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                        BluetoothDevice bt_device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                        if (bt_device.getAddress().equals(partnerDevAdd) == true) {
                            isConnected = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
private void connectToExisting(BluetoothDevice bluToothDevice) {
    new ConnectThread(bluToothDevice);
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `registerReceiver()` is not a `static` method. It is a regular method. Remove `Context.` from your `registerReceiver()` calls. Also, your `registerReceiver()` calls have, as their first parameter, `mReceiver`. `mReceiver` is not defined anywhere. Please replace `mReceiver` with something that is an instance of a `BroadcastReceiver`. Note that you cannot call `registerReceiver()` multiple times for the same `BroadcastReceiver` instance, so you probably want to have one `IntentFilter` for all of your actions and one `registerReceiver()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Context from the registerReceiver() method and move the code into the onCreate() method.

Here is the new version of the code with the changes:

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class BluetoothConnectionRepair extends Activity {
    //Assuming that the device address is registered and is connected
    private String partnerDevAdd = "11:22:33:AA:CC:FF";
    private boolean isConnected = true;

    IntentFilter bluetoothIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        bluetoothIntentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, bluetoothIntentFilter);
        bluetoothIntentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, bluetoothIntentFilter);
        bluetoothIntentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, bluetoothIntentFilter);
    }

    //BroadcastReceiver for Bluetooth related checks
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (isConnected == false) {
                //Bluetooth Device discovered
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    //Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    //Check if the discovered device is one we had communication with
                    if (device.getAddress().equals(partnerDevAdd) == true) {
                        connectToExisting(device);
                    }
                }

                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                    //Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    //Check if the connected device is one we had communication with
                    if (device.getAddress().equals(partnerDevAdd) == true) {
                        isConnected = true;
                    } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                        BluetoothDevice bt_device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                        if (bt_device.getAddress().equals(partnerDevAdd) == true) {
                            isConnected = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
private void connectToExisting(BluetoothDevice bluToothDevice) {
    new ConnectThread(bluToothDevice);
}
}
```